# Сборка OpenSSL из исходников

Tags: openssl, opensource

Всем доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь собрать OpenSLL из исходников для операционной системы Windows 10. Первоначально скачал git-scm. Затем клонировал репозиторий с github'a: `git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git`
Затем скачал и установил активную версию perl http://www.activestate.com/ActivePerl

После этого, по инструкциям, которые я находил я пытался сконфигурировать perl в x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt, запуская от имени администратора:

`perl Configure VC-WIN64 no-asm --prefix=C:\OpenSSL-Win64`

После этого, действуя по инструкции я пытался установить:

`nmake -f ms\nt.mak` и получаю ошибку fatal error u1052.

Возможно, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой. Или я что-то неправильно делаю, кто-нибудь кто собирал на Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2019? Подскажите, как правильно. Готовую сборку не предлагать, необходимо самому собрать.

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

А нам не нужно особых действий все описано в `INSTALL` файле.

1. Установить Visual Studio, NASM, Perl.
2. `git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git`
3. Переключиться на нужную ветку (`OpenSSL_1_1_1`) или тег (`OpenSSL_1_1_1d`).
4. Запустить `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` от администратора (или в следующей комманде указать `--openssldir` на папку к которой имеет доступ текущий пользовалеть).
5. `perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\OpenSSL-Win64`
6. `nmake`
7. `nmake test` (необязательно)
8. `nmake install`